# Specify certain string of text as bold while adding multiple strings to a single cell

Tags: excel, vba

I'm wondering if there is a way to dictate which text within a cell to bold without knowing the start or length of the characters. What I am needing to do is enter multiple strings(some user input)of text on separate consecutive lines within a single cell while making the predetermined strings (every other line) bold.

I am compiling the free text from multiple text boxes into the same cell on different lines using `chr(10)`. For example:

```
CmpTxt = myTxt1 & Chr(10) & userTxtBox1.value
CmpTxt = CmpTxt & Chr(10) & myTxt2 & Chr(10) & userTxtBox2.value

activesheet.range("A1").value = CmpTxt
```

Where each myTxt is bolded, followed by the user's text under it in the same cell, A1.

```
My first line of text posed as a question
Users' corresponding answer
My second line of text posed as a question
Users' second corresponding answer
```

Here I could use `.characters` to make the `myTxt1` bold, but because I have no idea how long the second line/user text will be, I cannot know where to start in order to bold the third line which is `myTxt2`.

Is there a way to predetermine `myTxt`'s as a bold font type when adding it to the string? If not is there a way to **a)** identify each line of text in the cell as if a row within a cell or **b)** find the specific strings of text that is `myTxt` or the character start,length of those strings and set only those to bold after adding the text to A1?

Comment: Split into a variant array on Chr(10) then cycle through the array from lbound(arr)+1 to ubound(arr) step 2.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution which simply uses the Chr(10) characters to determine where to start and end the bolding:

```
Sub HighLightIt()
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("A1")
    Dim p1 As Long
    Dim p2 As Long
    Do
        'point to the end of the question
        p2 = InStr(p1 + 1, rng.Value, vbLf)
        If p2 = 0 Then
            Exit Do
        End If
        With rng.Characters(Start:=p1 + 1, Length:=p2 - p1).Font
            .Bold = True
        End With
        'point to the end of the user input
        p1 = InStr(p2 + 1, rng.Value, vbLf)
        If p1 = 0 Then
            Exit Do
        End If
    Loop
End Sub
```

This will fail if any of the questions, or any of the answers, include a line feed.  You probably don't want the questions or answers to permit line feeds anyway, so you might consider using `Replace(userTxtBox1.value, vbLf, "|")` (or similar) when storing the questions and answers into your consolidated cell.

Answer (score 0):

Split into a variant array on Chr(10) then cycle through the array from lbound(arr)+1 to ubound(arr) step 2.

```
Dim arr As Variant, a As Long

With ActiveSheet.Range("A1")
    arr = Split(.Value2, Chr(10))

    For a = LBound(arr) + 1 To UBound(arr) Step 2
        With .Cells(1).Characters(Start:=InStr(1, .Value2, arr(a)), Length:=Len(arr(a))).Font
            .Bold = True
            .ColorIndex = 5
        End With
    Next a
End With
```

I threw in a blue font as well.

This will actually fail if the answers are identical but you can control that by advancing the start of the InStr by the previous answer lengths.

Comment: I reread your question and it seems like you want the questions bold, not the answers. Make appropriate adjustments to the above.